# New blender hair system is a lot more dense in some places other than other places

Tags: rendering, hair

New blender hair system is a lot more dense in some places other than other places

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: modifiers]

[image]

Comment: Do you have the *Surface Deform* modifier with the single *Deform Curves on Surface* node in it at the end of the modifier stack? Does it show a message? Is the emitter object (F_Head?) smooth-shaded?